# Bug with eclipse when using retrolambda and Android

Tags: android, eclipse, retrolambda

We're using gradle for builds, but writing with Eclipse. I have retrolambda working fine, eclipse sees the lambda syntax and is OK, gradle builds and runs perfectly.

The pnly problem is that Eclipse marks the files as having errors, with the 'p' of 'package' underlined in red, with the error

'The type java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files'

Anyone know how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution was to totally remove the Android facet of the project in eclipse, and set the eclipse project SDK to JDK8. Then when building with gradle and retrolambda it was set to compile on JDK7. We also needed to add the android jar to the eclipse build path.